# SQL Query optimization : is scalar subqueries killing the performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I need help on query optimization.

The below-mentioned query is just a sample. Actual query has 50+ scalar subqueries. Base table table_xyz has over 5 million records.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    seq,
    (
        SELECT
            function_abc(t.id,t.seq,115501)
        FROM
            dual
    ) AS txt_dosage_comments,
    (
        SELECT
            function_abc(t.id,t.seq,115502)
        FROM
            dual
    ) AS fld_txt_total_therapy_duration

FROM
    table_xyz t;
```

please check the screenshot of current explain plan

[image: please check the screenshot of current explain plan]

`function_abc()` reads data from another table which has 100million records. `table1` has been indexed on `(id, seq, field_id, language)` fields. There can be multiple records across the rows for one (id, seq) pair that's why there is a loop to concatenate them and make a string.

This is what function looks like :

```
    FUNCTION function_abc (
        pi_id     int,
        pi_seq    int,
        pi_field_id   int
    ) RETURN CLOB AS
        l_result   CLOB := NULL;
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (
            SELECT
                text
            FROM
table_1
            WHERE
                id = pi_id
                AND   seq = pi_seq
                AND   language = '001'
                AND   field_id = pi_field_id
            ORDER BY
                seq
        ) LOOP
            l_result := concat(l_result,rec.text);
        END LOOP;

        RETURN l_result;
    END;
```

Using Oracle 12c.

Comment: @APC I have updated the question and added the function's definition as well.

Comment: table has been indexed in id, seq, field_id, language fields

Comment: Oh boy. Fifty-plus multi-row selects with a loop concatenating a CLOB . *shakes head sadly*. So, the business logic here is not clear, which makes it hard to offer advice for improvement. One thing: your query joins on `seq = pi_seq` which suggests a 1:1 mapping. So why the loop? Or if there are multiple rows per `seq` what is the point of the `order by` clause?

Comment: @APC it's 12c. the function looks for records using id and seq. there can be multiple records across the rows for one (id, seq) pair that's why there is a loop to concatenate them and make a string.

Comment: The major reason this query is going to be slow is that you're doing a FULL TABLE SCAN on a table with 5+ million rows, and calling a function which loops over a cursor fifty times. That makes for 250 million function calls, which is going to be slow no matter how you cut it. You might try replacing the body of `function_abc` with `NULL;` to see just how badly the loop is hurting you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The scalar subquery, as written, is not killing performance.  The function call probably is.

You don't need the subquery.  Just write:

```
SELECT id, seq,
       function_abc(t.id, t.seq, 115501) as txt_dosage_comments,
       function_abc(t.id, t.seq, 115502) as fld_txt_total_therapy_duration
 . . .
```

Oracle has a pretty smart optimizer.  It would ignore the subquery in this case.

Judging from the names of the fields, the function is doing some sort of lookup in tables.  That would definitely be a performance killer on larger data sets.

Comment: But doesn't that lose the [scalar subquery caching](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/efficient-function-calls-from-sql#scalar-subquery-caching)? **Edit:** just noticed `t.id` and `t.seq` are part of the function call, so we can forget about any caching...

Comment: Converting my code into a snippet like this will kill caching.

Comment: @PrashantMishra . . . Unless you have a lot of duplicates in the data, there is no useful caching going on.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries with our without scalars are always a burden, more or less, and what is happening usually is that the burden becomes unacceptable later on.

One important factor is if the scalar function is not deterministic. A deterministic function will always return the same result upon supplied the same parameters. In general, anything that 'SELECT' cannot be deterministic as data may change. If it is deterministic then delays are limited to difference of supplied values.

For SELECT subqueries in overall it is better to try to join instead of using subquery at select clause. In most cases a join is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the answer to my question, with thorough explanations:
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1594885400346999596